# how to print dynamic port in nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

I want to print the dynamic port created by Nginx in reverse proxy mode, so as to capture the specific packet.

I have go through the nginx docs, but not find something useful. by the way, any other alternatives are welcome

Comment: Could you please share you config? IMHO the `proxy_pass` directive doesn't expose any dynamic port.

Comment: There is nothing like a dynamic port in nginx. You specify the port Nginx is going to proxy_pass, so that means you already know the port before hand. Are you looking to capture data between your nginx and the proxy_pass backend?

Comment: the dynamic port is not the specified backend port, is the port used by nginx to build tcp connection with backend app